# How to make sidebar's height equal to the content height (two columns table with divs)?

Tags: css, layout, html

I've created 2 columns layout - content div and sidebar div, with header and footer. See the live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cXGyS/). 
How can I make sidebar's height equal to the content height (i.e. I should have something equal to the table with 2 columns).

I use jquery and jquery ui.

Comment: Only with css it can be solved only in html5 standart. In html4 you can only use a tricks like: fake column in background picture, or using javaScript!

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? Specifically: do you need to support IE7?

Comment: @thirtydot, surely IE7 should be also supported.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `table` instead of `div`s then?

Comment: One of the most frustrating omissions in CSS 2.1 is the ability to create equal-height columns. As Alexander indicates, unless you want to go with JavaScript, can't be easily done. You just need to do searches for "equal height CSS columns" and pick a technique that works for you. Tables? Yes, that would work. As long as you don't mind being the object of scorn and derision. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this technique before to solve this exact problem and it works nicely:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/

Comment: PS: I should add that the normal way to do this is to "fake" it using CSS, but I'm guessing you actually want the <div> elements to actually have the same height, as opposed to just looking like they do.

Comment: Thanks. However I believe that for my case there should be much more easy solution ;).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a CSS solution, look into [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/). You essentially fake the column with a repeating background image. The linked article is just an example, you can Google up 100 articles on it.